# WCF: Proxy client class throws 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.oscarehr.org/", local:"arg0").Expected elements are <{}arg0>'

Tags: java, c#, wcf, soap, xml-namespaces

How can I fix the code and/or generated proxy class?
Should I change WSDL before generating proxy class?

I used svcutil.exe  /namespace:*,Oscar.Facades.ScheduleService https://test-oscar.com/oscar/ws/ScheduleService?wsdl to generate proxy classes for WCF service calling Java backend.

I am calling a service:

```
        ScheduleWsClient scheduleWsClient = new ScheduleWsClient(basicHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(scheduleServiceUrl));
        appointmentTransfer[] appointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider = scheduleWsClient.getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2), DateTime.Today.AddDays(3), provider);
```

and getting error:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.oscarehr.org/", local:"arg0"). Expected elements are <{}arg2>,<{}arg1>,<{}arg0> '

From above error message, I understand arg0 belongs to default namespce "http://ws.oscarehr.org/", and actually needs to belong to no namespace which was supposed to be enforced with xmlns="" declaration.
(Namespace prefixes can also be overridden by redeclaring the prefix at a nested scope)

The body that is sent looks like this:

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider xmlns="http://ws.oscarehr.org/">
   <arg0 xmlns="">2019-01-18T00:00:00-05:00</arg0>
   <arg1 xmlns="">2019-01-19T00:00:00-05:00</arg1>
   <arg2 xmlns="">1</arg2>
  </getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

while when trying this request in SoapUI with this either of these modified payload it does work:

```html
<ws:getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider xmlns:ws="http://ws.oscarehr.org/">
  <arg0 xmlns="">2019-01-18T00:00:00-05:00</arg0>
  <arg1 xmlns="">2019-01-19T00:00:00-05:00</arg1>
  <arg2 xmlns="">1</arg2>
</ws:getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider>


<ws:getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider xmlns:ws="http://ws.oscarehr.org/">
  <arg0>2019-01-18T00:00:00-05:00</arg0>
  <arg1>2019-01-19T00:00:00-05:00</arg1>
  <arg2>1</arg2>
</ws:getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider>
```

Based on [Understanding XML Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa468565(v=msdn.10)) article when a default namespace is declared on the parent element of arg0 like

```
        <getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider xmlns="http://ws.oscarehr.org/">
```

arg0 xmlns="" means we can undeclare a default namespace above.

we undeclare a default namespace by simply setting the default namespace identifier back to the empty string. As a result, the arg0 element doesn't belong to a namespace.

I really don't understand why arg0 would still belong to the default namespace:
"http://ws.oscarehr.org/" despite the fact I undeclared it.
To me all 3 requests are identical.

Update:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider", WrapperNamespace="http://ws.oscarehr.org/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.oscarehr.org/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public System.DateTime arg0;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.oscarehr.org/", Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public System.DateTime arg1;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.oscarehr.org/", Order=2)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string arg2;

    public getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider()
    {
    }

    public getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider(System.DateTime arg0, System.DateTime arg1, string arg2)
    {
        this.arg0 = arg0;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your proxy class, are xmlelement namespaces defined on the properties for arg0 arg1 arg2?

Comment: @Popo I updated my post to include method and argument definitions automatically generated by svcutil.exe. Do you see anything wrong? Is this about .net vs. java expected proxy class/method/argument definitions and if I need to do some manual adjustments of wsdl or generated proxy. Or I need to do something special when calling proxy methods

Comment: I would try deleting this line for each of the args: `[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.oscarehr.org/", Order=0)]`

Comment: I cannot remove the whole row otherwise arg0... arg2 won't be sent to the service.  So I need to have MessageBodyMemberAttribute attribute. I tried removing Namespace property, but the result is the same

Comment: hmm, not too sure then, did you try setting the namespace to empty string? you might want to fiddle around a little try changing iswrapped to false. I have had issues like this before and my solution was just getting rid of the namespace attribute, or maybe try setting the namespace to empty string in the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute, just some suggestions. These things can be hard to figure out since WCF will create proxy classes differently than how SOAPUI processes the requests. Is the namespace getting included in the outgoing soap message?

Comment: I tried all of this. The first <s:Body message above is how it is send raw on the wire with WCF. Only when I prefix getAppointmentsForDateRangeAndProvider element explicitly it works. Only in that case arg elements are in the required namespace (or n namespace). However based on generated proxy code WrapperNamespace is the same for parent and arg elements.